# How can I send a date using a AXIOS Get?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to send a date like

```
        2007/08/01 00:00
```

as one of the values in my AXIOS GET

```
      https://restapi.azurewebsites.net/api/PublicationReport/" +
      dbid +
      "/" +
      sortDate
```

As you can tell it plays havoc with the Web API controller

```
        <Route("api/PublicationReport/{dbid}/{sortDate}")>
```

The controller thinks that every "/" is a new parameter.

Is there a special format that must be used or do I need to send it as a json object?

I went with

```
      params: {
      dbid: dbid,
      sortDate: sortDate
    },
```

on the client side and below for the server side

```
Public Function GetValues(dbid As Integer, sortDate As String) As String
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create an object like this:

```cs
public class SomeQuery
{
    public string SomeParameter { get; set; }
    public int? SomeParameter2 { get; set; }
}
```

And then in controller just make something like that:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult FindSomething([FromQuery] SomeQuery query)
{
    // Your implementation goes here..
    //then you can access query value using HttpContext.Request.Query
}
```

or using method params

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult FindSomething(string value1, string value2)
```

Comment: I went with the params method and I updated my question - Thanks